# Overriding datetime parsing in XmlSerializer without changing generated code

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, code-generation, xmlserializer

I am accessing a third party API and retrieving some XML.  I was also able to access the xsd for it and I use the xsd to generate objects for deserialization using XmlSerializer.

The XML contains dates like this:

```
<modified>2014-08-19T06:39:13.269-0400</modified>
```

The generated code looks like this:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="time")]
    public System.DateTime modified {
        get {
            return this.modifiedField;
        }
        set {
            this.modifiedField = value;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this results in errors when attempting to deserialize.

I can work around this by marking it with a XmlIgnore attribute and adding code like this to a partial class:

```
    [XmlElement("modified")]
    public string modifiedAsString
    {
        get { return this.modified.ToString(); }
        set { this.modified = System.DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }
```

However, the ignore part is a change to the generated classes and I'd have to make hundreds of these changes to account for all of the datetimes.

I tried the MetadataType thing to apply the attribute to it from the outside but unfortunately XmlSerializer doesn't pick that up.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can parse this without changing the generated code or the input XML (which is out of my control)?

Comment: If you are willing to change your `System.DateTime` to a custom wrapping class with implicit operators to/from `System.DateTime` it's possible. Though I suspect this may be even more of a breaking change than the ignored helper property.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to change your `System.DateTime` to a custom wrapping class with implicit operators to/from `System.DateTime` it's possible. Though I suspect this could be even more of a breaking change than the ignored helper property.

You can create a custom type that will wrap an underlying `DateTime` and perform the necessary to/from parsing. In addition, you can take advantage of the [`XmlTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to control the output to match the `<modified>2014-08-19T06:39:13.269-0400</modified>` schema:

```
public struct CustomDateTime
{
    private DateTime UnderlyingDateTime;

    [XmlText]
    public string CustomFormat
    {
        get { return UnderlyingDateTime.ToString(); }
        set { UnderlyingDateTime = System.DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(CustomDateTime custom)
    {
        return custom.UnderlyingDateTime;
    }

    public static implicit operator CustomDateTime(DateTime datetime)
    {
        return new CustomDateTime { UnderlyingDateTime = datetime };
    }
}
```

And here's the class that contains the `Modified` property (you didn't mention the name, so I'll just call it `Foo`):

```
public class Foo
{
    public CustomDateTime Modified { get; set; }
}
```

The implicit operators allow you to read/write `DateTime` values directly in most cases:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.Modified = DateTime.Parse("2014-08-19T06:39:13.269-0400");
```

It supports your standard flare `XmlSerializer` serialization:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
var textwriter = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(textwriter, f);

string xml = textwriter.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

The resultant XML (I've stripped some of the wrapping junk that would normally be in your root node) is:

```
<Foo>
  <Modified>2014-08-19 6:39:13 AM</Modified>
</Foo>
```

Deserializing that above XML:

```
Foo deserialized = (Foo)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

DateTime datetime = deserialized.Modified;

Console.WriteLine(datetime);
```

Results with the `DateTime` output: `2014-08-19 6:39:13 AM`

Now, this doesn't match the XML content *exactly*, that is it shows "2014-08-19 6:39:13 AM" instead of "2014-08-19T06:39:13.269-0400", but only because I'm following *verbatim* your use of `DateTime.ToString()` and `DateTime.Parse` for the `get/set` property as you have it.

However, it will read in the XML content just fine, that is, if your incoming XML is:

```
<Foo>
  <Modified>2014-08-19T06:39:13.269-0400</Modified>
</Foo>
```

It still reads it the same way (essentially it will call `System.DateTime.Parse("2014-08-19T06:39:13.269-0400")`).

EDIT: Just to clarify, the breaking change you would have to make would be changing your original `Foo` class from this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}
```

To this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public CustomDateTime Modified { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not positive if the behaviour of the `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="time")]` attribute is emulated correctly in this usage, but if it isn't, you easily have to flexibility to implement *whatever* parsing you wish within the `CustomDateTime.CustomFormat` property getter and setter.